# C++11 std::thread segment fault

Tags: multithreading, c++11

This program ended with segment fault. Why ?

```
#include <thread>

void f(){}

int main(){

    while(true){
        std::thread t(f);
        t.join();
    }
}
```

environment: winxp+mingw+gcc4.8

Comment: ran out of resources .. you should check

Comment: this seems to be the same underlying issue that appears here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432848/is-it-ok-to-call-stdasync-at-high-frequency

Answer (score 1):

The program should not cause any resource problem, for at the end of each loop, the thread finishes its execution and the thread object is destroyed.

I ran the slightly modified code below on Win 7 64 bit compiled with VS 2013 Update 3. While I was typing this answer, the counter reached more than 880,000 without any error.  Therefore, the problem may be with your environment.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void f(){}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    while (true){
        std::thread t(f);
        t.join();
        std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
    }
}
```