# Is it OK to call std::async at high frequency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I have a little program I wrote that uses `std::async` for parallelism, and it is crashing on me. I'm pretty sure that there are much better ways to do this, but for now I just want to know what is happening here. I'm not going to post the exact code since I do not think it really makes a difference. It basically looks something like this:

```
while(1)
{
    std::vector<Things> things(256);

    auto update_the_things = [&](int start, int end) { //some code };

    auto handle1 = std::async(std::launch::async, update_the_things, 0, things.size() / 4);
    auto handle2 = std::async(std::launch::async, update_the_things, things.size() / 4, things.size() / 4 * 2);
    auto handle3 = std::async(std::launch::async, update_the_things, things.size() / 4 * 2, things.size() / 4 * 3);
    update_the_things(things.size() / 4 * 3, things.size());

    handle1.get();
    handle2.get();
    handle3.get();
}
```

This loop runs several thousand times per second and after a random amount of time (5 seconds - 1 minute) it crashes. If I look in task manager I see that the thread count for this program is rapidly fluctuating, which makes me think that `std::async` is launching new threads with each call. I would have thought it would work with a thread pool or something. In any case, is this crashing because I am doing something wrong?

Using GDB I get the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 3560.0x107c]
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

#0 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1 0x000000000041d18c in pthread_create_wrapper ()
#2 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Output from gcc -v as requested:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-2 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (tdm64-2)
```

Comment: " I would have thought it would work with a thread pool or something" That's completely implementation defined, you should probably see how and where it crashes to be able to answer your question.

Comment: you should especially check if this is the case: `Throws std::system_error with error condition std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again if the launch policy equals std::launch::async and the implementation is unable to start a new thread `

Comment: @PeterT I put a try/catch around the `std::async` part and it caught nothing. I simply get a "this program has stopped working" message. I tried using gdb but this slows the program down to the point where it does not trigger the crash. It only seems to happen when the loop is running particularly fast. Gdb does confirm that every call to async launches a new thread.

Comment: Oh, you're using gcc on Windows? Yeah, I don't think gccs implementation is too thoughtful at the moment (msvc might use the native thread pool mechanics in Win8 and later). Does the program crash not show a reason in the event log or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you show the code of `update_the_things` with the crash ?

Comment: @PeterT I was able to speed gdb up by disabling thread-event messages. I posted the output in the question.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm just looping through a vector of items and doing a tiny bit of math, nothing interesting.

Comment: @Chris_F what's the output of `g++ -v`

Comment: @PeterT Information added to the question.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this occasional crash with G++ (g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2) on Windows 7 32-bit. Seems to be a race in the standard library.

Comment: @Casey yeah, I think so too, the question is though, is this an error in the stdlib or is this caused by the incomplete implementation of `winpthreads`?

Comment: Oh, just FYI I couldn't reproduce this error on gcc 4.9.0 with cygwin and someone in the minigw irc chat said the nightlies are working for him too, so this error has already been fixed

Comment: @PeterT It's great they fixed the bug, now if only they would improve the implementation of `std::async` a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This standard-conforming program also crashes, and usually much faster:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
  try {
    for (;;) {
      std::async(std::launch::async, []{}).get();
    }
  } catch(...) { std::cout << "Something threw\n"; }
}
```

It's a bug in the implementation.

Comment: well does it show something when you do `catch(std::exception &ex){std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;}`? Because if you just forgot to add `-pthread` to the compile flags this can also happen on some gcc versions

Comment: No solution for that?

Comment: btw. this works without any issues on gcc 4.6.3 and 4.8.2 on Ubuntu Linux. The launch::async implementation of gcc is indeed primitive and just instantiates a std::thread , so this should be reproducible with just `std::thread t([](){});t.join();` instead of the async call

Comment: why would this crash, just due to out of resources? how is it a bug?